# Яндекс карта, по клику на внешнюю ссылку открывать балун и центрировать карту

Tags: jquery, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Есть [карта](http://jsfiddle.net/AJIEKCEU/Leu6dvjr/) с метками и балунами(яндекс api 2.1), и есть список адресов вне карты. по клику на этот список нужно открывать балун, и центрировать карту, все вроде сделал, но по клику почему-то не всегда открывает нужный балун, что не так? Очень нужна помощь!

```
// По клику на адрес, открывает балун и центрирует карту
     $('.filter-result').on('click', '.filter-result__item', function(){
            $(".filter-result__item").removeClass('filter-result__item_active');
            $(this).addClass('filter-result__item_active');
            var pos = $(this).find('.shop-address').text();
            var indexObj = $(this).index();
            //номер метки
            var point = myMap.geoObjects.get(indexObj);
            //координаты метки
            var npoint = $.map(point.geometry.getCoordinates(), Number);
            //центрирование карта
            myMap.setCenter(npoint, 13, {checkZoomRange: true,
                }).then(function () {
                  //открыть балун
                  point.balloon.open();
                }, function (err) {
                }, this);
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

В общем нашел интересный момент, запихав в console.log() myMap.geoObjects, я увидел что ответы геокодера могут приходить в разном порядке, и получается что индексы всегда разные, не такая последовательность как я добавлял изначально, решил проблему Костылем((. [Вот результат](https://jsfiddle.net/AJIEKCEU/6brtgw2g/)

По клику я считаю количество всех адресов, после чего цыклом беру адрес на кликнутом элементе, и сравниваю с массивом объектов что возвращает карта, правда и тут очень не красивым способом `point.balloon._geoObject.properties._data.balloonContent`
сравниваю 2 строки адресов, и если ровно, то открываю балун

```
$('.filter-result').on('click', '.filter-result__item', function(){
      $(".filter-result__item").removeClass('filter-result__item_active');
          $(this).addClass('filter-result__item_active');
          var pos = $(this).find('.shop-address').text();
          var indexObj = $(this).index();
          var lengthOng = $(".filter-result__item").length;
          for(var i = 0; i < lengthOng; i++){
              //номер метки
              var point = myMap.geoObjects.get(i);
              //координаты метки
              var npoint = point.geometry.getCoordinates();
        var balloonCont = point.balloon._geoObject.properties._data.balloonContent;
              if(pos === balloonCont){
                myMap.setCenter(npoint, 13, {checkZoomRange: false});
                point.balloon.open();
              }
          }
   });
```

Если кто знает как без такого костыля обойтись, буду признателен.